# Using Different, Aggregated Column as Column Name in Slicer

Tags: powerbi

I'm new to Power BI and trying to create a slicer for Classes by Instructor.  The best value to display to the user is the name, since that is how users normally identify the instructors.  The problem is that some instructors have had name changes.  This actually leads to two problems:
1. How to roll the duplicates up into one item in the slicer selection options, and 
2. How to use the combined underlying DimIDs for actually slicing the data.

Sample source table structure looks like this:

```
InstructorDimID  InstructorID  InstructorName
---------------  ------------  --------------
1                1             John Smith
2                2             Karen Jones
3                2             Karen Watson
4                3             Jennifer Anderson
5                3             Jennifer Hancock
```

Would like the slicer to look like this:

```
Jennifer Hancock
John Smith
Karen Watson
```

I have an idea of how I would do this in SQL but don't know if it's at all relevant for Power BI.  I tried searching stackoverflow as well as Power BI sites with no luck; am looking for an approach that will help me learn how to "think in Power BI".  Any tips are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be a part of your data model.

Either add a new table keyed by InstructorID that has the current name of each Instructor, and a relationship with filter flow to your existing InstructorDim, or add a CurrentName column to your existing InstructorDim.

Comment: Thank you!  This is very helpful